# How do you put significant letters over my variables in a boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to add significant letters over my variables to show significance. I have already seen this can be done with a #text script option but I am having trouble getting it to work. From what I can gather from reading other posts, I think my problem is coming from the #par script.

This is the script I have so far:

```
#par(mfrow=c(4,2), mai=c(.1,.6,.02,.1), oma=c(5,1.5,3,0.5))
#boxplot(log(Data$Ag) ~ Site, data=Data, xaxt='n', ylab="Ag Concentration (?g/g)",cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.3, whisklty=1, staplewex=.5, whisklwd=1.5, outcex = 1.5, cex = 1, boxfill=8)
#boxplot(log(Data$As) ~ Site, data=Data, xaxt='n', ylab="As Concentration (?g/g)",cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.3, whisklty=1, staplewex=.5, whisklwd=1.5, outcex = 1.5, cex = 1, boxfill=8)
#boxplot(log(Data$Cd) ~ Site, data=Data, xaxt='n', ylab="Cd Concentration (?g/g)",cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.3, whisklty=1, staplewex=.5, whisklwd=1.5, outcex = 1.5, cex = 1, boxfill=8)
#boxplot(log(Data$Cr) ~ Site, data=Data, xaxt='n', ylab="Cr Concentration (?g/g)",cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.3, whisklty=1, staplewex=.5, whisklwd=1.5, outcex = 1.5, cex = 1, boxfill=8)
#boxplot(log(Data$Cu) ~ Site, data=Data, xaxt='n', ylab="Cu Concentration (?g/g)",cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.3, whisklty=1, staplewex=.5, whisklwd=1.5, outcex = 1.5, cex = 1, boxfill=8)
#boxplot(log(Data$Fe) ~ Site, data=Data, xaxt='n', ylab="Fe Concentration (?g/g)",cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.3, whisklty=1, staplewex=.5, whisklwd=1.5, outcex = 1.5, cex = 1, boxfill=8)
#boxplot(log(Data$Hg) ~ Site, data=Data, ylab="Hg Concentration (?g/g)", cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.1, whisklty=1, staplewex=.5, whisklwd=1.5, outcex = 1.5, cex = 1, boxfill=8)
#boxplot(log(Data$Zn) ~ Site, data=Data, ylab="Zn Concentration (?g/g)", cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.1, whisklty=1, staplewex=.5, whisklwd=1.5, outcex = 1.5, cex = 1, boxfill=8)
```

Thus produces this:
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U037a.jpg)

I know this can be done in ggplot, but before starting over, I wanted to see if there was an option to do this.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What text do you want to add and where?

Answer (score 0):

You can add text to plots using `text`. On boxplots, the x coordinates are ordered form 1 to *n* (*n* being the number of boxes). For example for plotting the text `"A"` above the first box in the first boxplot:

```
par(mfrow=c(4,2), mai=c(.1,.6,.02,.1), oma=c(5,1.5,3,0.5))
boxplot(log(Data$Ag) ~ Site, data=Data, xaxt='n', ylab="Ag Concentration (?g/g)",cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.3, whisklty=1, staplewex=.5, whisklwd=1.5, outcex = 1.5, cex = 1, boxfill=8)
## Adding "A" above the first box
text(1, 1.7, "A")
```

If you want to add bars (e.g. for significance between two boxes you can use `lines`:

```
par(mfrow=c(4,2), mai=c(.1,.6,.02,.1), oma=c(5,1.5,3,0.5))
boxplot(log(Data$Ag) ~ Site, data=Data, xaxt='n', ylab="Ag Concentration (?g/g)",cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.3, whisklty=1, staplewex=.5, whisklwd=1.5, outcex = 1.5, cex = 1, boxfill=8)
## Adding a line above the first two boxes
lines(x = c(1,2), y = c(1.6, 1.6))
## Adding a significance token above the line
text(1.5, 1.7, "*")
```